# ik service call fails

Tags: ros, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing a little IK work with a 7-DOF arm using ROS' IK service calls but with little luck. I want the ability to use either the collision free IK or just the regular IK service. I can connect to and see the /get_ik, /get_ik_solver_info, and /get_constraint_aware_ik with no problem, but when I send the solver a pose, I get the error:

`Inverse kinematics service call failed`

If I run the collision free IK with the same exact pose, it has no problem finding a solution and returning from the service. I can dig through the service calls and try and hunt down why it might err when the only difference is which service I connect to, but I was hoping someone here may know the culprit or why it may be acting up like this.

I might also add that yesterday before I left work, I had the get_ik service call working with no issues. Today, without changing a single thing, I have yet to be able to return successfully from the ik service call. I have restarted my simulation multiple times and verfied the rosservice is started as well as any controller I need.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12436/ik-service-call-fails/) by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest that you try changing the resolution that the IK solver works in. In your constraint_aware launch file, add a parameter of:

```
 <param name="arm/epsilon" value="0.001" />
```

Where "arm" is the name of your arm. The default value is 1e-5, I've found that 1e-3 or 1e-4 tends to work better for my arm.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0